# How to increase size of filesystem to match partition

Tags: filesystems, partition, lvm, gparted, resize2fs

Apologies for this question but I am very new to Linux. 
When I installed my Fedora distribution I only allocated 20GB of my hard drive space for its partition. I recently used GParted and tried to increase the size of the partition to around 40GB. I was under the impression that I was successful but today I tried to create a directory and I got the following error message:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘b_scripts’: No space left on device
```

I checked the space on my disk and found out that I had used 20GB on my fedora-root.

```
derrick@dazza >> df -h 
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                 1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    1.9G  253M  1.7G  14% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    1.9G  1.5M  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                    1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/fedora-root   20G   19G     0 100% /
tmpfs                    1.9G  128K  1.9G   1% /tmp
tmpfs                    386M   20K  386M   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                    386M   28K  386M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Is a partition different from a Filesystem? How come there are only 20GB in total allocated to my fedora-root? 
What is my solution? How do I increase the size of my fedora-root Filesystem so that it is more than 20GB Size?

Comment: Could you exchange the `df -h` output with the one of `df -hT`. Also add the output of `lvdisplay`, `cat /etc/crypttab` and `parted -l`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, your file system is on the LV(Logical Volumne), which is on the partition. If you expand the partition, your LV will not be expanded.

Please run these commands :

`pvresize <device name>` <-- This will let the Physical Volume know that the partition it is on has been expanded.

And :

`lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/fedora-root <Physical Volume name>` <-- This will extend the LV.

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/fedora-root
```

PS: You can find the Physical Volume name using the command `pvs`

Thank you @Dani_l for the edit suggestions.

Comment: Better to use `lvextend -l +100%FREE` and you forgot `resize2fs` at the end (or the xfs or btrfs or ... equivalent. need output of mount to know which fs is used).

Comment: I have carried out the steps and at the `lvextend` command gave me this result which indicates that it worked. `Size of logical volume fedora/root changed from 19.53 GiB (5000 extents) to 46.97 GiB (12025 extents).` However at the `resize2fs` I get `resize2fs 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
Usage: resize2fs [-d debug_flags] [-f] [-F] [-M] [-P] [-p] device [-b|-s|new_size] [-z undo_file]` which means I'm missing some options but I'm not sure which since I'm not too familiar with the language for example `device`

Comment: Can you show me the output of `df -Th` , if it worked, mark it as correct.

Comment: `devtmpfs                devtmpfs  1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                   tmpfs     1.9G   96M  1.8G   5% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   tmpfs     1.9G  1.5M  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                   tmpfs     1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/fedora-root ext4       20G   19G     0 100% /
tmpfs                   tmpfs     1.9G  128K  1.9G   1% /tmp
tmpfs                   tmpfs     386M   20K  386M   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                   tmpfs     386M   28K  386M   1% /run/user/1000` I suspect the last command didn't work.

Comment: did you run `resize2fs`?

Comment: yes I ran the command by itself and it gave me the usage prompt. I'm thinking maybe I need to run it with some options but the manual is beyond my understanding.

Comment: Run `resize2fs /dev/mapper/fedora-root`

Comment: `pvresize` requires an argument-- such as `pvresize /dev/sda2`.